# Where can I download the installer for the "Microsoft Report Viewer 2014 Runtime"?

Tags: reporting, reportviewer, microsoft-reporting

My reports are acting up so I'd like to reinstall the runtime to see if that helps, but all I can find on it is that it is available as either a NuGet package or as part of SQL Server Developer Edition, which requires an MSDN subscription. Is there anywhere else I can get the installer for this tool? I'm looking specifically for version 12.0.2000.8. The tool is installed on the server but when I try to run a repair on it, it asks for installation media, which I don't have.

Comment: Look this man: https://github.com/codeulike/crisscross/wiki/Report-Viewer-Version-History